# Split object into smaller parts

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I want to split the object I get out of results into variables.

I only get undefined as result.
Anyone got any ideas?

```
app.get('/bets/:id', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;

    function(err, result) {
      var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM bets WHERE id = ?', [id], function(err, results, rows) {
        //res.json(results[0]);
        var test = results.creator
        console.log(test);
      });
    });
```

Comment: If you don't use an ORM I think the result of your query will be an array of values instead of an object. Have you tried *console.log(results)* ? what's the output ? I guess it's an array like `[ 'myCreator', 'myField2' ]`

Comment: It looks like this
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    description: 'ww',
    title: 'qq',
    password: 'eee',
    creator: 'rr',
    hours: 11 } ]

I figured this was an Object? I might be wrong!

Comment: Ok so it's an array of objects, @Derick Bailey's solution looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [ RowDataPacket { id: 2, description: 'ww', title: 'qq', password: 'eee', creator: 'rr', hours: 11 } ]

The result you're getting is an array, noted by the `[ ]` square brackets.

To get the data you want, you need to pull the first item (index 0) out of the array, and then get the values:

```
var bet = results[0];
var test = bet.creator
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!